# Convert integer to date in R and sort by date using sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I am trying to load a data set in R which has USERID and Date. I am trying to pull the MIN(DATE) for the userID using sqldf but seem to have a problem with the result.

I converted the date column using posixct and checked the typeof column and it showed double(it was integer before the conversion)

```
test$C_DATE <- as.POSIXct(test$C_DATE, format = c("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"))
minDate <- sqldf("SELECT U_ID,MIN(C_DATE) AS FTrans FROM test WHERE U_ID = 'ABC' GROUP BY U_ID")
```

The expected Output should be

```
U_ID FTrans
ABC  12/20/2017  5:00:47 PM
```

But i get

```
U_ID FTrans
ABC  1507631400
```

I tried to use the incorportate the date function in SQL as the below query

```
minDate <- sqldf("SELECT U_ID,DATE(MIN(C_DATE),'unixepoch','localtime') AS FTrans FROM test WHERE U_ID = 'ABC' GROUP BY U_ID")
```

But I get the wrong date and also the wrong format as a result.

```
U_ID FTrans
ABC  2017-10-10
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
UID    C_DATE
ABC    10/11/15 9:05
ABC    10/11/15 20:08
DEF    10/11/15 11:37
GHI    10/11/15 20:08
JKL    10/11/15 2:46
```

Ideally for User ABC I want the first recorded data(MIN DATE) i.e. 10/11/15 9:05

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data? may use `dput(your data)` and paste here.

Comment: I have added the sample data in the question now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) sqlite** The problem is that sqlite (the default backend) does not have a date/time type so the POSIXct values are sent and returned as raw numbers.  It is not possible to know for sure whether a number returned from sqlite is supposed to represent a POSIXct value but what sqldf does is guess based on its name.  Since C_DATE is POSIXct in the input it will assume that any C_DATE column returned should be converted to POSIXct so just use C_DATE as the column name rather than FTrans.  Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we use:

```
library(sqldf)
test$C_DATE <- as.POSIXct(test$C_DATE, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

sqldf("SELECT UID, MIN(C_DATE) AS C_DATE
  FROM test 
  WHERE UID = 'ABC' 
  GROUP BY UID")
```

giving:

```
  UID              C_DATE
1 ABC 2015-10-11 09:05:00
```

There are also other methods of telling sqldf the column types if you read `?sqldf`.

**2) h2** The other way to deal with this is to use the h2 backend database as it does support date/times.  If the RH2 driver is loaded sqldf will notice it and use that database backend instead.  This is the same as in the question except fixed up to use the correct column names.  As before we use `test` from the Note below.

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT UID, MIN(C_DATE) AS FTrans 
  FROM test 
  WHERE UID = 'ABC' 
  GROUP BY UID")
```

giving:

```
  UID              FTrans
1 ABC 2015-10-11 09:05:00
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "UID,C_DATE
ABC,10/11/15 9:05
ABC,10/11/15 20:08
DEF,10/11/15 11:37
GHI,10/11/15 20:08
JKL,10/11/15 2:46"
test <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
test$C_DATE <- as.POSIXct(test$C_DATE, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Actually the Column name did the trick. RH2 package takes a long time to compute when i join multiple tables. Any reason you may know why?

Comment: The first time you use java in a session it will have to load java so that takes a long time and maybe that is what you are observing.  Try it twice.  If it really does take a long time you can try adding an index to your table or use a different back end.

Comment: I tried several times but it still takes a long time. Maybe adding the index will work - thanks for the tip.!

Answer (score 0):

This answer belongs to comments, but I don't have enough reputation to post a comment.

The format argument in `as.POSIXct()` is the format that the function is going to encounter rather than the final format. So, you'd need first to tweak the call to `as.POSIXct()`:

```
test$C_DATE <- as.POSIXct(test$C_DATE, format = c("%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```

After finding the min date using sqldf, you can reformat the date using `format.POSIXct()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried changing the format in the POSIXct but i still get the date and the format wrong for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with package `library(tidyverse)`

```
> test %>% 
+   group_by(UID) %>% 
+   summarize(mindate = min(C_DATE))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  UID   mindate            
  <chr> <dttm>             
1 ABC   2015-10-11 09:05:00
2 DEF   2015-10-11 11:37:00
3 GHI   2015-10-11 20:08:00
4 JKL   2015-10-11 02:46:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I need it in sqlf.